# Calendar.vim E492: Not an editor command: Calendar

Tags: vim, osx, macintosh, gvim, vimrc

I am trying to install the calendar.vim plugin on mac osx snow leopard running gvim. I have pathogen.vim installed, so I followed the instructions on github to install calendar.vim from the terminal:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone git://github.com/mattn/calendar-vim
```

I've got it, and everything appears to be where it is supposed to be, as far as I can tell, but it isn't working. I type `:Calendar` a get the error:

```
E492: Not an editor command: Calendar
```

I've tried `:calendar` also, I have restarted vim and no luck. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

After doing these commands:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone git://github.com/mattn/calendar-vim
```

You need to add the following line to your $HOME/.vimrc file:

```
Bundle 'calendar-vim'
```

After doing this when I start up vim I get the command:

```
:Calendar
```

Which shows the following in vim.

#### screenshot

[image: ss of vim w/ calendar plugin]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your *Pathogen* setup isn't working.

Check that

```
:set runtimepath?
```

contains `~/.vim/bundle/calendar-vim`.

With `:scriptnames`, you can check which files have been sourced; to be successful, there must be a `plugin/calendar.vim` in there.

It's difficult to troubleshoot the particular Pathogen problem with that little information, sorry; I hope you can figure it out.

Comment: `~/.vim/bundle/calendar-vim` is in the runtime path, but it's not listed in the scriptnames. I'll try to reinstall pathogen